# How to show or dismissed a message at startup when the start screen is changed in KivyMD Python?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm a Beginner to Python. I want to dismiss a message, if the starting screen is screen1 in my KivyMD App. If the starting screen is screen2 or any other screen the message should always be displayed. How would I do that?

**Here is my Code.**

---

```
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton, MDRaisedButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog

screen_helper = """

ScreenManager:
    Screen1:
    Screen2:
    
<Screen1>:
    name : 'screen1'
    
<Screen2>:
    name : 'screen2'
    
"""


class Screen1(Screen):
    pass


class Screen2(Screen):
    pass


class Mode(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(screen_helper)

    def on_start(self):
        self.add_songs_dialog = MDDialog(
            title="Add Songs",
            text="Your Albums are Empty.Mode has been either restored or Albums have been Deleted."
                    "\n\nYou should add Songs to Launch Mode.",
            buttons=[
                MDFlatButton(
                    text='Later', font_style='Button'
                ),
                MDRaisedButton(
                    text='Add Songs', font_style='Button', md_bg_color=self.theme_cls.accent_dark
                ),
            ],
        )
        self.add_songs_dialog.open()

Mode().run()
```

---

I tried several ways but I could not find the right solution.  Please help me.

Comment: Do a tinier example please, you have a lot of stuff that is non-essential for this question like `'E:\K75 Programming\Python\Mode\ModeInfo/'` which makes the app crash. No need to store stuff too. `JsonStore`

Comment: @Utopion , Thank you for the response. Actually this isn't the original program. I wrote it very short.  In the program I want to Show the message only if  the `'E:\K75 Programming\Python\Mode\ModeInfo/'` directory is empty. And also if there is no a file named `std_profile.json` the screen should be navigated to the screen1. I want to dismiss the message if the starting screen is screen1. Otherwise the message should be shown. Please help me to do this successfully.

Comment: Okay but your question is takling about **How to show/hide message when screen appears ?** which has nothing to do with a condition on a file existing and registering a json which means you could have simplified your code more. Which means I have to do it myself. Which means I may help other people that takes time to do what they can and ask for what they don't know. (No pression, I was like you before, I'm just giving you reasons and advices on how and why you should do better questions)

Comment: @Utopion, Thank you sir for teaching me to improve my question asking style. I have edited my question. Now, I think I made it as simple as necessary. Is that correct? Or should it be further corrected?

Comment: If I copy/paste it, your code isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

screen_helper = """
ScreenManager:
    Screen1:
    Screen2:

<Screen1>:
    name : 'screen1'
    MDFlatButton:
        id: button
        text: "Go to Page 2"

<Screen2>:
    name : 'screen2'
    MDFlatButton:
        id: button
        text: "Go to Page 1"

<CustomPopup>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: dp(350), dp(300)
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    MDLabel:
        text: 'I am displayed on every screen except "screen1"'
"""


class Screen1(Screen):
    pass

class Screen2(Screen):
    pass

class CustomPopup(Popup):
    pass

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(screen_helper)

    def change_screen(self, name):
        self.root.current = name
        if not name == "screen1":
            CustomPopup().open()

    def on_start(self):
        self.root.get_screen("screen1").ids["button"].bind(on_press=lambda w: self.change_screen("screen2"))
        self.root.get_screen("screen2").ids["button"].bind(on_press=lambda w: self.change_screen("screen1"))

MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Sir @Utopion, Now it runs properly. Thank you so much.